# Placing Labels on the left side of a CheckBox in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

i would like to place my Label of a CheckBox on the right side, but i dont know how to do it. Can anybody help me?

Has it anything to do with the funciton labelDisplay?

Comment: Is there any "labelPlacement" property on your combo ?  in flex you can use <mx:CheckBox  labelPlacement="right" label="Label"/>

Comment: there's no labelPlacement property on spark CheckBox. the proper way to change the placement would be to change it in skin.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy spark's `CheckBox` skin and modify it.
You will find this skin in

```
FlexSDK\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\skins\spark\CheckBoxSkin.mxml
```

The main `Group` block contains the box itself, add to its tag `right="0"`

At the bottom you will find the `Label`, just change `left="18" right="0"` to `left="0" right="18"`

Dont forget to affect the skin to the component in your css:

```
s|CheckBox { skinClass:ClassReference("mypackage.CheckBoxSkin"); }
```

Comment: <s:Group verticalCenter="0" width="13" height="13" layoutDirection="ltr" right="0">    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="start"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             left="0" right="18" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" /> I tried it, but it doesnt work. If i place the Checkbox, the text is still on the right side.

Comment: hmm this works for me. did anything change? did you apply the skin correctly? maybe you can try changing something else in the skin to make sure the skin is applied correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is to use layout direction property layoutDirection="rtl"

```
<s:CheckBox label="Mutant Technologies" layoutDirection="rtl"/>
```